# ckeditor conflicting with double quotes from html rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

Ck editor formats the text applying the class properties wrapped in double quotes but for some reason, my application keeps rejecting this format, I am collecting a form content and passing the data to a JSON.stringify to create a .json file that holds the textarea field content, on save the formation added to the html containing double quotes conflicts and the json understands that the double quotes are a separation of the object.

so it crops the beginning of the formation of the tag, in this example it repeated the end of the frase where i only formated the red line, but on refresh it comes back with a **">** lost somewhere from the last line of the text formated.

[image: ckeditor quote conflict]

and if checked the code of the string the formated text doesnt have an opening tag.

[image: ck editor quote conflict]

Some help is much appreciated and rewarded.

I would like to be able to format the text content without the double quotes if possible.

**UPDATED**

THE RAW JSON from the entire form with 3 fields.

```
{"qualifyAmount":"35","above_price":"<p>You just got a superb <strong>Free Shipping</strong> with your order values of <span style=\"font-size:14px\"><span style=\"color:#c0392b\">cartPriceTotal</span></span></p>\n","below_price":"<p>You get <strong>free</strong> shipping when ordering &pound;35+, just add another... cartPriceRemaining</p>\n\n<p><span style=\"color:#c0392b\">Limited offer!</span></p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n"}
```

Comment: You need to fix your code to handle double-quotes.

Comment: Show us how the json is created and handled. Using proper json serializers typically does all the needed escaping

Comment: I updated the questiong showing the raw json created from the text fields 2 of the fileds are using ckeditor #above_price #below_price

Comment: For some reason, it works fine if I get the liquid content to render in a another textarea then get the content like: $("textarea#above_price").text($(".successMessage").text()); and save it I get a proper code formatation! but yet I have to duplicate the content in order to obtain a proper one why wont it just format correctly the content withthe liquid inserted to the #above_price textarea?

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this:

before saving the editor content to the database and file I do this first:

```
$content = htmlspecialchars($editorcontent, ENT_QUOTES);
```

and when retrieving the content from the database I do this prior to loading it into the editor:

```
html_entity_decode($contentfromdb, ENT_QUOTES);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: So you suggest to get the string from the editor format it without the quotes or escaping it to save it to the database then render them again formatted? I am using liquid to render the textarea code I am not sure but it could be mostly the liquid which is outputing things wrong but i tried all filters to format the output escaped, replacing the quotes but for some reason because its html content the editor loops it again to double quotes causing this conflict